# AJAXFileUpload with Title Textbox

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

Fairly straightforward.  I'm just looking for users to be able to add a title to the file before uploading.  (Yes, I encourage proper filenames, but that's not the point.)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDocumentTitle" />
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload runat="server" ID="ajxUploadNDA" OnUploadComplete="ajxUpload_Complete" Width="400px"   /><br />

    protected void ajxUpload_Complete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        MyFile f = new MyFile();
        f.DocumentType = e.ContentType;
        f.FileBytes = e.GetContents();
        f.FileName = e.FileName;
        f.DocumentCategory = "Package Files";
        f.FileUploaded = DateTime.Now;
        f.DocumentTitle = txtDocumentTitle.Text;
        f.Save();

        DataBind();
    }
```

However when setting a breakpoint, txtDocumentTitle.Text is always blank.  I can't seem to force a full postback or find any other way to get the current value of that textbox.  I can allow the user to edit those properties *after* the file is uploaded, but that is not the design I'd prefer for a few reasons. (It encourages leaving values at default.)

I've tried:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(ajxUploadNDA);
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).SupportsPartialRendering = false;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).EnablePartialRendering = false;

    }
```

and I've tried

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload runat="server" ID="ajxUploadNDA" OnUploadComplete="ajxUpload_Complete" Width="400px" onchange="if (confirm('Upload ' + this.value + '?')) this.form.submit();"  />
```

Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've sort of solved it by adding a button to "Set Document Title" which adds the value of the textbox to session.  The ajxUpload_Complete function then uses this Session variable to set the title to that session value on upload.

It's sloppy for a couple reasons, but it's the best I could do.

On Page_Load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack && !ajxUploadNDA.IsInFileUploadPostBack)
{
  Session.Remove("DefaultDocumentCategory");
  lblDocumentCategory.Text = "Data Package Files";
  Session.Remove("DefaultDocumentTitle");
  lblDocumentTitle.Text = "Data Package File";
}

protected void btnChangeDocumentAttributes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDocumentCategory.Text = cboDocumentCategory.SelectedValue;
    lblDocumentTitle.Text = txtDocumentTitle.Text;
    Session["DefaultDocumentCategory"] = lblDocumentCategory.Text;
    Session["DefaultDocumentTitle"] = lblDocumentTitle.Text;
}
```

I also added a dummy button to the page to force a postback refreshing my gridview that shows all the files uploaded.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnForcePostBack" runat="server" Text="" Style="background-color: Transparent; color: inherit; border-style: none;" />

protected void ajxUpload_Complete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{

    MyFile f = new MyFile();
    f.DocumentType = e.ContentType;
    f.FileBytes = e.GetContents();
    f.FileName = e.FileName;
    f.FileUploaded = DateTime.Now;

    if (Session["DefaultDocumentCategory"] == null || Session["DefaultDocumentCategory"].ToString() == string.Empty) f.DocumentCategory = "Data Package Files";
    else f.DocumentCategory = Session["DefaultDocumentCategory"].ToString();
    if (Session["DefaultDocumentTitle"] == null || Session["DefaultDocumentTitle"].ToString() == string.Empty) f.DocumentTitle = "Data Package File";
    else f.DocumentTitle = Session["DefaultDocumentTitle"].ToString();
    f.Save();
    ajxUploadNDA.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshParent", "<script type='text/javascript'>var btn = window.parent.document.getElementById('btnForcePostBack');if (btn) btn.click();</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of these other answers to work.  I ended up putting the textbox on an ajax update panel.  Then I created an event for the textbox OnTextboxChanged that stored the value in the session.  Then I could grab the value in the UploadComplete right from the session.

Answer (score 0):

When using ajax upload, you can only save right away, then second step would be to have separate call to get file from saved location and operate on it.  I was having same issue with multiple asynchronous upload using Uploadify and Uploadifive.  My first step when uploading multiple files is to save to temp location, then have second call to retrieve it, resize it and save it to cloud (Azure Storage).  Its impossible to put a break point, since the threads are all over the place.  Its a strange behavior, specially when uploading a single file, but that's the best solution to first save then retrieve using separate call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AjaxFleUpload control use hidden frame for submitting file content. You may use script below to pass textbox value to server:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);

function applicationLoadHandler() {
     var originalCreateForm = Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._createVForm;

     Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._createVForm = function () {
          originalCreateForm.call(this);

          var textBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
          textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
          textBox.setAttribute("name", "<%= txtDocumentTitle.UniqueID %>");
          textBox.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("<%= txtDocumentTitle.ClientID %>").value);

          this._vForm.appendChild(textBox);
     }
}
```

On server you can get user input from `Request.Form` collection:

```
var title = Request.Form[txtDocumentTitle.UniqueID];
```

Comment: In the code behind, I have
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "StartupScript", "Sys.Application.add_load(function() { applicationLoadHandler(); });", true);
    }
And on the .aspx page:
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function applicationLoadHandler() {
    var originalCreateForm = ...prototype...= function ()  {
    originalCreateForm.call(this);
    ...
    this._vForm.appendChild(textBox);
     }
    }
    </script> 
Yet anything I try with Request.Form is always null.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment.  In short, I tried everything I could think of with this code and Request.Form was always null.

Comment: @Serinus, when you script, registered with `RegisterStartupScript` method executes, Application.load event already passed so you don't need to register function for overriding AjaxFileUpload as event handler. Try to place script in my answer right below the ScriptManager control on a page or change startup script to `applicationLoadHandler();` without attaching this function to `Sys.Application.load` event